# zsh: stdout and stderr both to console AND log

Tags: zsh, redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm converting a script from bash to zsh and have been floundering for days with the output.  I want the stdout and stderr to both go to both the console and a log file.  I've tried everything I can find online but no joy.  I've read the redirection section of the zsh manual but found nothing that helped, although I must admit it is unclear to me.

Here are the things I've tried near the beginning of the script, experimentally, and their result:

```
exec 2>&1 | tee -i test.log     # everything in console, log created but empty
exec 2>&1 | tee -i > test.log   # everything in console, log created but empty
exec 1>>$LOG; exec 2>&1         # everything in log, none in console
exec 2>&1; exec 1>>$LOG         # console gets errors only; log stdout only
exec &> >(tee "$LOG")           # works in bash, error in zsh
exec > >(tee -i ${LOG?}) 2>&1   # error
exec |& tee $LOG                # error
exec > >(tee $LOG) 2>&1         # error
```

I also tried to understand the zsh option multios, but couldn't make much sense of it.  It's supposed to be on by default, but I don't find it in the list of options when I run `setopt`.  Nor when I run `setopt multios`.  When I run `unsetopt multios`, I see the option `nomultios`, but that doesn't seem to help

I understand that similar questions have been asked and answered, but the answers are mostly in the list above and have not worked for me.

I don't think it's relevant, but I also set up a debug log that gets file descriptor 3.  It's just for debug output lines that are ended with >&3.

Note for anyone looking for such a solution: The above exec trials were done with a messed up shebang, and the results with that corrected were a bit different.  In addition to the solution by Gairfowl, below, this also worked:

```
exec > >(tee $LOG) 2>&1
```

Comment: Is that a literal `exec` that's used or did you replace your executable name with confusing `exec`?

Comment: @Destroy666, I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but the script literally says "exec".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
exec >&1 >>log.txt 2>&1
print -u1 stdout stuff
print -u2 stderr info
```

Testing:

```bash
> ./testexec
stdout stuff
stderr info
> cat log.txt
stdout stuff
stderr info
```

Change `>>log.txt` to `>log.txt` if you want to overwrite the file each time rather than appending to it. This also worked with `>>$log` when the `log` variable was set to a filename. The `multios` syntax is described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134760), and there's a bit more info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/673145).

This does require that `multios` be enabled - as you noted, that is the default. `set -o` (nb: set, not setopt) can be used to display the status of all of the options; `setopt` without parameters only lists options that have been changed from the default.

Some notes on the pieces:

- `exec ...` - the `exec` builtin will replace the current shell with a new process. When it's invoked like this without a command argument, the replacement is another instance of `zsh`, with the redirects set to the new values in the command line. The effect is almost identical to invoking a command with those redirects on the command line, e.g.
  `{print abc;print -u2 def} >&1 >log.txt 2>&1`.
- `>&1` - redirect `stdout` to `stdout`. Yes, it's a bit redundant - this is a signal to `multios` that we want to continue to send `stdout` to its current destination (which is probably the terminal) in addition to the following redirects.
- `>>log.txt` - add a redirect of `stdout` to the file `log.txt` in append mode. This is a `multios`-specific behavior; now the standard output is being sent to two places, via a mechanism in `zsh` that looks a lot like `tee`.
- `2>&1` - send `stderr` to the same place as `stdout`. Thanks to the previous two redirects, `stdout` is going to two places, so this also sends `stderr` output to the file and (probably) the terminal.
- `print -u<n>` - just for testing. The `-u` option sends the output to file descriptor `<n>`.